# Como fazer uma consulta SQL com alguns critérios em branco?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

estou criando um filtro para uma busca num banco de dados numa aplicação PHP e obviamente tenho inúmeros critérios, mas, só tenho conseguido fazer funcionar com apenas um critério.

Código:

```
select codigo, despesa, data, estabelecimento, valor from financeiro where codigo = 603;
```

Assim ele, obviamente, funciona perfeitamente.

No entanto, numa página eu preciso deixar em branco alguns critérios, como no exemplo.

Na hipótese de que o usuário deixou o campo estabelecimento vazio, no entanto, ele não retorna nenhum valor, quando deveria mostrar o mesmo que a primeira consulta.

```
            <?php 
    include "conexao_bd.inc";

    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $hora = $_POST["hora"];
    $despesa = $_POST["despesa"];
    $valor = $_POST["valor"];
    $modo = $_POST["modo"];
    $observacao = $_POST["observacao"];
    $estabelecimento = $_POST["estabelecimento"];
    $genero = $_POST["genero"];
    $tipo = $_POST["tipo"]; 


    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, "select * from financeiro where codigo like '$codigo' and data like '$data' and hora like '$hora' and despesa like '$despesa' and valor like '$valor' and modo like '$modo' and observacao like '$observacao' and estabelecimento like '$estabelecimento' and  genero like '$genero' and tipo = '$tipo'");

    //Escrevendo a tabela.
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td><strong>Código</strong></td><td><strong>Data</strong></td><td><strong>Hora</strong></td><td><strong>Despesa</strong></td><td><strong>Valor</strong></td><td><strong>Modo</strong></td><td><strong>Observação</strong></td><td><strong>Estabelecimento</strong></td><td><strong>Gênero</strong></td><td><strong>Tipo</strong></td></tr>"; 


    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$linha['codigo']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['data']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['hora']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['despesa']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['valor']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['modo']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['observacao']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['estabelecimento']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['genero']."</td>
        <td>".$linha['tipo']."</td>
        </tr>";      

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

?>

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Grato.

Comment: Voce disse que a segunda "deveria mostrar o mesmo que a primeira consulta". O que significa que na primeira consulta vem estabelecimentos vazios, é isso? Quantos registros tem no banco hoje, cujo código seja 603 e também o campo estabelecimento é vazio?

Comment: Então é porque eu estou utilizando isso com PHP, daí se o usuário não colocar parâmetros, eles precisar ir em branco, certo? Mas o parâmetro precisa estar lá pro usuário poder optar por digitar. 

No caso se o usuário deixar o campo estabelecimento vazio ele precisa retornar o mesmo que se tivesse buscado apenas o código 603.

Comment: Entao nao faz sentido sua query. Omita o `and estabelecimento=''` sempre que o campo estiver em branco, que fica mais simples. Você pede só os registros 603 em branco, só vai vir se tiver as 2 situações. Melhor você [edit] sua pergunta, colocar as tags certas então, e explicar seu problema direito, senão o pessoal perde tempo respondendo coisas que não vão te servir, e seu problema vai continuar sem solução decente. Sugeriria você aprender PHP e SQL com coisas mais simples, depois que entender o básico passa para coisas mais complicadas.

Comment: Certo, eu não me expressei de forma adequada, Bacco. Fiz uma edição tentando explicar melhor.

Comment: O meu problema é passagem de parâmetro quando o usuário não usa todos os parâmetros, mas, apenas alguns, ou apenas um.

Comment: Pode ser que  o campo esteja com valor padrão `null`.  Vide a resposta do @Skywalker

Comment: E como eu mudaria isso isso?

Comment: No caso, como eu poderia deixar na passagem do parâmetro para ele simplesmente omitir o null.

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro pelo que entendi você não deveria passar a coluna `and estabelecimento = '';`. Adiciona na clausula somente se o usuario preencher o filtro.

Comment: em todos os filtros eu uso o LIKE. A não ser que o valor venha de algm combobox, se for digitado mete o LIKE que resolve seu problema.

Comment: Pessoal, em PHP como eu omitiria o and estabelecimento = '' e os outros parâmetros caso o usuário não o preencha?

Comment: @GustavoTinoco, eu tentei usar o like e não deu certo.

Comment: Atualizei o código, o meu problema é com a passagem de parâmetro na hora de fazer a busca no banco.

Comment: @GustavoTinoco, corrigindo, o like funciona quando eu executo a instrução SQL no phpMyAdmin, mas, quando o faço pelo mysqli_query ele não traz nada.

Comment: Bom Eduardo Ribeiro, minha experiência se limita ao uso de funções mysqli_query pois até hoje só trabalhei com os métodos PDO Orientado objeto de banco, caso se interesse meu projeto está aqui: https://github.com/gustinoco/Sislabweb   (fiz no estágio na embrapa) os métodos de tratamento com o banco estão na pasta /entidade/

Comment: Veja que a resposta indicada no fechamento resolve pra qualquer comparador, seja `in`, `=`, `LIKE`. O que ela faz é deixar de fora a comparação se o parâmetro for vazio, e você pode aplicar nos parâmetros que desejar (que é exatamente o que eu tinha sugerido no 2o comentário, omitir a comparação e o campo caso o valor seja vazio).

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado, fui concatenando a instrução SQL como sugeriu o Skywalker e deu certinho. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente

```
estabelecimento is NULL
```

FONTE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html

**UPDATE**

No seu caso, crie o sql de forma concatenada.

```
$sql ="select.... where codigo=$codigo ";
if(!empty($estabelecimento))
  $sql.=" AND/OR estabelecimento=$estabelecimento ";
if(!empty($campoX))
  $sql.=" AND/OR campo_x=$campoX ";
```

> Nunca insira variavel diretamente no sql igual foi feito, totalmente inseguro, use sempre prepared statements para adicionar parametros dentro do sql.

Comment: Deu certinho, amigo, sua dica foi muito valiosa. Você é o cara, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito de se conseguir isso é:

```
select codigo, despesa, data, estabelecimento, valor from financeiro where codigo = 603 and LTRIM(RTRIM(estabelecimento)) = ''
```

Assim se tiver espaços também será considerado como vazio.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo.